Female assassin recruited from Death Row
The movie was made in the 90's I think. 
It begins with a woman, who is a criminal and is about to get her death penalty, which is lethal injection. Later when she wakes up and realizes that she was saved by a spy/hitman organisation and begins to work for them. 
After a while she meets a man and falls in love with him. She keeps her relationship with him as a secret and don't tell him what she does for a living. In the end she kills her boss because he finds out about the affair and she breaks up with her boyfriend because she's scared that someone might come after him.

You are looking for Point of No Return (1993)
Also known as Codename: Nina and The Assassin.


Drug addict Maggie Hayward's consistent violence, even in police
  custody, ends in the execution chamber. However, top-secret US
  government agent 'Bob' arranges a staged death, so Maggie can be
  elaborately trained as a killer. She gets a new cover identity as
  saleswoman Claudia Anne Doran. She also finds a house-mate, building
  super J.P., a broad-minded, gentle photographer. The two fall in love,
  and that complicates her government assignments. His influence extends
  to breeding in her a conscience that supplants her violent tendencies
  and desire to continue work for the agency.

Trailer

I concur it's more likely this remake than the original, but the Q is partly mistaken: Bob learns about her relationship and accepts it and uses it as part of her cover; the 'friendly' she kills is Victor The Cleaner, a co-worker assigned on one (big) job who is about to kill her, and she then leaves but J.P is not blamed or endangered.

It sounds like Nikita to me. The plot summary on Wikipedia is

In prison, her captors fake her death, making it appear that she has committed suicide via a tranquilizer overdose. She awakens in a nondescript room, where a well-dressed but hard-looking man named Bob (Tchéky Karyo) tells her that, although officially dead and buried, she is in the custody of a shadowy government agency known as "the Centre" (possibly part of the DGSE). She is given the choice of becoming an assassin, or of actually occupying "row 8, plot 30", her fake grave. After some resistance, she chooses the former and proves to be a talented killer. She is taught computer skills, martial arts, and firearms. 

It was made in 1990.
There was also a TV show based on this where she had a secret boyfriend who was a fellow assassin.

Nikita (aka: La Femme Nakita) was the European version of the movie the OP is talking about and came out prior to that version, which @Dannie properly identifies from the description given in the question.
